# Match Shipments to Invoice isn't inserting Vendor Doc Number

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-gp

I'm fairly new at using GP for areas beyond HR & Payroll, so please forgive my ignorance of process'/workflows.

We had a Purchase Order in which one line item was cancelled by the vendor. However, after receiving the other items from the order and completing the invoicing and posting for it, we received the line item we had been told was cancelled from that PO. We created a new PO for just that one line item and named it related to the first (po's "12345" and "12345A"). Purchase Order Document Inquiry shows a valid, unique Receipt number for just that new PO.
When we now try to match the shipments to invoice, we're able to pull up the appropriate PO (12345A) and line item, but have to manually input "Quantity Invoiced" and the "Matched to Shipment is blank" following the blue arrow shows us 0 options for Shipment Receipt numbers.
The PO is in status "Released" as is the line item, but using "Edit Purchase Order Status" to try to change to "Received" gives an error "You can't change the status of this line item; it has unposted receipts assigned to it"

The receipt number does exist in POP10500 with the correct details, does appear in POP10300, but without a vnddocnm (not sure if it should), and does not exist in POP10600.

What should be my next steps be to be able to match invoice/purchase order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the error message was at the heart of the fix: "You can't change the status of this line item; it has unposted receipts assigned to it".... surprise surprise, our 3rd party product we use to automatically post items for us, had run into an error posting a Sales Order, and hadn't moved on to post any other BATCHES. Fixing that error, allowed all pending BATCHES to complete posting, and the Receipt was then able to be added to the Match.